# Do I need to seal the food with food wrap before put them in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator

I've always seen friends putting leftover, cooked food in the fridge with food wrap. I asked them why they are doing it and they don't even know why they are doing it. It is necessary to put just cooked food in the fridge with food wrap?

Comment: If you often have leftovers, reusable containers are probably a lot easier than using plastic wrap for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping food in plastic wrap before refrigerating has a few obvious benefits:

1) keeps the food from drying out in the fridge.

2) prevents odors (garlic, onions, fish, etc.) from transferring between the item in question and everything else in the fridge.

3) keeps crumbs, extraneous particles from falling into the food. If there were a lot of mold/microbe life already proliferating in the other refrigerated goodies, it might even serve to slow down slightly their penetration into your new leftover food on intra-fridge air currents (...ovbviously I'm reaching here)

But no, you don't *have* to use the plastic wrap; it's just a custom.

Comment: "Custom" is a rather weak word for something that, as you say, provides really clear benefits. And (3) isn't really a reach at all. Airborne contamination may not generally be that rapid or severe, but it's real, so leaving everything uncovered will increase the odds of faster spoilage. The [FDA specifically says to always cover things](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm093704.htm#2), in the context of safety.